# Enabling disabled fieldsets under certain radio button selection contitions

Tags: javascript, forms, ecmascript-6

Here’s what I want to achieve:

> Remove `disabled` attribute from the `baz` fieldset only after both of these conditions are met:
>
> 1. If `one` or `two` is checked.
> 2. After any `bar` radio input is checked.

So if `three` is selected, then don't remove `disabled` attribute from `baz` fieldset after any `bar` input is checked.

I know how to solve the first condition listed above, but not the second. What am I missing?

```js
const form = document.forms[0]
const foo = form.elements.foo
const bazFieldset = form.querySelector("fieldset:last-of-type")

foo.forEach(foo => {
  foo.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (foo.value != "three") {
      bazFieldset.disabled = false
    } else {
      bazFieldset.disabled = true
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
  <label><input type=radio name=foo value=one>One</label>
  <label><input type=radio name=foo value=two>Two</label>
  <label><input type=radio name=foo value=three>Three</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <label><input type=radio name=bar value=four>Four</label>
  <label><input type=radio name=bar value=five>Five</label>
  <label><input type=radio name=bar value=six>Six</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset disabled>
  <label><input type=radio name=baz value=seven>Seven</label>
  <label><input type=radio name=baz value=eight>Eight</label>
  <label><input type=radio name=baz value=nine>Nine</label>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would attach a `change` listener to the container, rather than assign a listener to each element, and use a helper function that can take in a selector string as an input, and will output whether an element matching that selector is checked:

```js
const bazFieldset = document.querySelector("fieldset:last-of-type")
const isChecked = selectorStr => document.querySelector(selectorStr + ':checked');
document.forms[0].addEventListener('change', () => {
  const enabled = (
    (isChecked('[value="one"]') || isChecked('[value="two"]'))
    && isChecked('[name="bar"]')
  );
  bazFieldset.disabled = !enabled;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label><input type=radio name=foo value=one>One</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=foo value=two>Two</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=foo value=three>Three</label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <label><input type=radio name=bar value=four>Four</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=bar value=five>Five</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=bar value=six>Six</label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset disabled>
    <label><input type=radio name=baz value=seven>Seven</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=baz value=eight>Eight</label>
    <label><input type=radio name=baz value=nine>Nine</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```